# Running the Background process in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios5

i am developing application for iPhone, here i need to have a background process which should check the current system time and match the set time in the variable, if time matched it should issue a command to connect to the server and this process should execute in every two hours and this should be run till the application is in the device.

Please provide me any sample code or suggestions

Thanks in advance

Comment: iOS(i mean Apple) will not accept that logic, instead send Push Notifications from your server to your app.

Comment: Other than push Notification is der any other way to do that..?

Comment: Really short answer NO, you might try `UILocalNotification` but if the user does not open your app noting will happen.

Comment: @user1557103, rckoens has answered right. It is not so difficult push notifications, i can help you either